# how do you convert user input datetime to epoch time in python

Tags: python, epoch

I need to convert user input datetime to epoch time. This what what I have:

```
from datetime import datetime
 
from_date = str(input('Enter date(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm): '))
to_date = str(input('Enter date(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm): '))
 
print(from_date)
2022-03-03 06:00:00
print(to_date)
2022-03-03 06:00:00

epoch = datetime.datetime(from_date).strftime('%s')
print(epoch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [date format codes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_date_format_codes.asp) and convert it to a datetime object, then simply use `.timestamp()`.

```
from datetime import datetime
from_date = "2022-03-03 06:00:00"
epoch = datetime.strptime(from_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp()
```

Comment: it give decimal, any ideas?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) the return type of `timestamp()` is float, i imagine this is because you want to be able to differentiate milliseconds etc aswell (e.g. `datetime.strptime("2022-03-03 06:01:01:001000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f").timestamp()`). If your smallest unit is seconds and you do not want decimals, simply convert to int: `epoch = int(datetime.strptime(from_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp())`

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your input to a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Then use [`dt.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) to convert to EPOCH:

```py
from datetime import datetime
 
from_date = str(input('Enter date(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm): '))

dt = datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
epoch = dt.timestamp() 

print(epoch)
# 1646287200.0
```

###### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxC8IwEIX3/IoDCU3AlJhKlYCj4OLk5CTFVNrh0pCeQ399TAr2eMM93vdeWGiYfJPSJ04IrqOeRuxhxDBF2jwDVvJX8XCBmaIYffiSqK6e@rhyYsmnEJVzMAwWUVqopGTMUa78l@rcDeUR2@AeKv5UHBV3wG@W3y1/VJL1YXoPpUl14WfqMAgJOzi0x9acT0brWjMW4uhJrLBMyWhjlG6yQLdW66wf)